# How to formulate x != y in lpsolve?

Tags: linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm trying to formulate that the variables x,y,z must all be different and that they accept only the values 1, 2 or 3 (this is, of course, a toy example):

```
min: x+y+z;

1 <= x <= 3;
1 <= y <= 3;
1 <= z <= 3;
```

but to make this work I still need either access to boolean operators or to a != operator, which don't seem to exist in lpsolve! How can I go about this? I wanted to do this:

```
x != y;
x != z;
y != z;
```

Thanks

EDIT:

Here's my current code:

```
/* Objective function */
min: 1;

/* Variable bounds */
1 <= x1 <= 4;
1 <= x2 <= 4;
1 <= x3 <= 4;
1 <= x4 <= 4;


x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 10;

x1 < x2;
x2 < x3;
x3 < x4;

int x1;
int x2;
int x3;
int x4;
```

lpsolve is giving me as result:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 3
x3 = 3
x4 = 3
```

which is wrong. Why?

Comment: Can't you just force `x<y` and `y<z`?

Comment: I thought about that, but the "and" doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Sure it does, you just add two constraints, constraints are always "and" each other

Comment: Ah, I see. But @MichaelLaffargue that way I'll be forcing an order on x, y and z, right?

Comment: In this case it isn't (but ofc, this is a toy example). I imagine this something more complicated in more realistic scenarios :(

Comment: Unfortunately it seems lpsolve is in some way "ignoring" the added restrictions (I've put the code in the OP). It's not really ignoring the added lines because the result is different whether I add the restrictions or not, but it effectively doesn't enforce them. Why?

Comment: Is that even a valid constraint format? I'd expect it to want `x1 - x2 <= -1`

Comment: It didn't complain about the format, but I will try your suggestion. EDIT: tried it. it makes no difference!

Comment: Well, that's pretty weird. By the way as for your original question, you can express that using an extra binary variable for both options (ie if it is zero then `x < y`, if it is 1 then `x > y`). Unfortunately that helper variable will tend to be chosen 0.5 in the linear relaxation.

Comment: From the doc `There is no semantic difference
  between "<" and "<=" nor between ">" and ">=" (even for integer
  variables!).`

Comment: Oh god? Nice find! If I put x1 < x2 + 1; it will work fine!

Comment: Try to take a look here : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.lpsolve/1402.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would agree with Michael Laffargue that it is not possible to have something like `a < b` for real a,b in lpSolve. But for integer expressions that is a bit different.

Maybe we can start with a more simplified problem.
Let us think of two integer variables x and y and a constant M such that
`1 <= x <= M and 1<=y<=M`.
If x and y may not be equal then x>y or y>x. But as both are integers **only one** of the following inequalities hold

```
x+1 <= y
y+1 <= x
```

We can enforce that only one of the inequalities above holds by introducing a binary variable r such that for x,y, r the following inequalities hold **both** :

```
(i)   x+1 <= y+ Mr
(ii)  y+1 <= x+M-Mr
```

because if `r=0` then `(i) x+1 <=y` and (ii) is trivial, but if `r=1` then `(ii) y+1 <= x` and (i) is trivial.

When we now apply the solution from above to the problem of the OP, then we can build a linear program with inequalities (i) and (ii) for all pairs of variables from the OP's problem and `M=4`:

```
/* Objective function */
min: 1;

/* Variable bounds */
1 <= x1 <= 4;
1 <= x2 <= 4;
1 <= x3 <= 4;
1 <= x4 <= 4;
r_12 <= 1;
r_13 <= 1;
r_14 <= 1;
r_23 <= 1;
r_24 <= 1;
r_34 <= 1;

/* This is done automatically because all x1,..,x4 are different
   x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 10;
*/

/*  Apply (i) and (ii) to all pairs of x1,..x4
(i)  x+1 <= y + Mr
(ii) y+1 <= x + M-Mr
*/

x1 + 1 <= x2 + 4 r_12;
x2 + 1 <= x1 + 4 - 4 r_12;

x1 + 1 <= x3 + 4 r_13;
x3 + 1 <= x1 + 4 - 4 r_13;

x1 + 1 <= x4 + 4 r_14;
x4 + 1 <= x4 + 4 - 4 r_14;

x2 + 1 <= x3 +  4 r_23;
x3 + 1 <= x2 + 4 - 4 r_23;

x2 + 1 <= x4 + 4 r_24;
x4 + 1 <= x2 + 4 - 4 r_24;

x3 + 1 <= x4 + 4 r_34;
x4 + 1 <= x3 + 4 - 4 r_34;

/*
x1 < x2;
x2 < x3;
x3 < x4;
*/

int r_12;
int r_13;
int r_14;
int r_23;
int r_24;
int r_34;
int x1;
int x2;
int x3;
int x4;
```

Solving the MILP above renders a solution with all `x1,..,x4` different:

```
x1=3
x2=1
x3=2
x4=4
```

Comment: Furthermore the above solution can be extended for non-integer variables. Assuming for the variables `x`and `y` (which shall not be equal, but bounded) it can be deduced from the modeled problem that there is a constant `C >0` s.t. either `x+C <=y` or `y+C <=x` holds