# Writing tiered pricing as a linear program

Tags: linear-programming

Is there a way to write a cost function that uses tiered pricing as a linear program?

```
supplier   volume A   price A   volume B   price B
1          0          $1        300        $2
2          0          $3        500        $1.50
```

By tiered pricing I mean for supplier 1, the first 300kg costs $1 and the second 200kg costs $2. (Not if I reach over 300kg, then all units cost $2). This is the cost function that I am currently looking at.

```
cost = P1a * V1 + P1b * V1 + P2a * V2 + P2b * V2

s.t     V1+V2 = 1000
        V2 < 8000, V1 < 800
where
P1a = first price bracket for supplier 1
P1b = second price bracket for supplier 1
V1 = volume for supplier 1
```

If it was the case where all volume is becomes price B when volume B is reached, then a I can add a binary variable so the function looks like this

```
cost = u * P1a * V1 + v * P1b * V1 + x * P2a * V2 + y * P2b * V2

s.t     u+v = 1, x+y = 1

u,v,x,y = 1 if price bracket is used, 0 if price bracket isnt used
```

Is there a way I could do something similar?

Edit:
V1 and V2 are both integers and have a set upper cap, lets say 800kg. There is also a demand constraint, lets say V1 + V2 = 1000.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be feasable, provided there is a constant `M>=0` which is a common upper bound for the volume variables `V1` and `V2` (e.g if there is a resriction `V1+V2 <=M`).
Provided that there is such an `M`, let us introduce two binary variables `b_1` and `b_2` which indicate (meaning having value 1) if `V1>= 300` and `V2>=500`  respectively:

```
300 * b_1 <= V1 <= 300 * (1 - b_1) + M* b_1
500 * b_2 <= V2 <= 500 * (1 - b_2) + M* b_2
```

Now we introduce non-negative variables `a_1, h_1` which will decompose `V1` into a part less than 300 (denoted by `a_1`)and a part holding the part exceeding (denoted by variable `h_1`):

```
V1= a_1 + h_1
h_1 <= M b_1
300 b_1 <= a_1 <= 300
```

The last two constraints with the binary variable enforce that `h1` will only be positive if `V1 >= 300`  and  `a_1` will always be 300 if `V1 >= 300`.
Let us do the same for `V2` respectively

```
V2= a_2 + h_2
h_2 <= M b_2
500 b_2 <= a_2 <= 500
```

Then the cost function will be

```
$1 * a_1 + $2 * h_1  + $3 * a_2 + $1.5 * h_2  
`
```

Let me remark that this solution might not be correct on boundaries e.g. when `V1=300`, because then the binary variable `b_1` might attain value 0  and thus `a_1=0, h_1>0`.
However this problem could be solved if the volumes `V1` and `V2` would be always integer values, e.g. see
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569008/how-to-formulate-x-y-in-lpsolve/52911179#52911179)

***Addendum to J.Doe's comment**:

if `V1` is an integer then the boundary problem would be treated by `301 b_1 <=V_1 <=301 (1-b_1)+ M b_1` instead of the defining condition for `b_1` above.

No, `h_1 < = M b_1 - a_1` is not valid because this would mean `V1 = a_1 + h_1  <= M b_1` which would imply `V1 = 0` if `V1 >=300` - which is not true.

Yes, `h_1` is the excess volume above the first bracket right.

If we have more than one price bracket we would need 2 further variables: One representing the amount which represents the volume `V1`'s share between the current price bracket and the next pricebracket.
The second variable should be a binary indicator variable which is `1` if the volume `V1` is between the current price bracket and the next pricebracket.

Comment: V1 and V2 are integer and have a set upper cap (editted). In this case, shouldn't h_1 < = M b_1 - a_1? h_1 represents any excess volume above the first bracket right? Also, if there were multiple price brackets, a new variable would be required for each bracket?

Comment: Made an addendum with respect to your comment. Please see above.